# Avro IDL for Rest Api input validation in python

Tags: python, flask, avro

We've been using Avro IDL to define message sets used on our Kafka back end and are quite happy with it.  We've also been interested in tying to validate `JSON` to a REST api on a Python Flask app with the Avro Schema as well and have been running into some difficulty.

There are a variety of packages out there but I have yet to find something that clearly works the way I need it to.  I'm hoping for some guidance.

I can take my `avdl` file and generate a set of `avsc` files with:

`avro-tools idl2schemata message.avdl output_dir`

or

`avro-tools idl message.avdl > output_dir/schema.avsc`

And I'm able to read these in python but I've found nothing "easy" that can just tell me if my JSON input matches the schema.

Has anybody done something similar?  Am I going down the wrong path?  Any advice would be appreciated thanks.

I know if I was playing in the SpringBoot land this would likely be VERY simple.

Thanks

### IDL

```
@namespace("org.jeeftor.avro")
protocol TacoRequest {

enum MeatType{
  CHICKEN,
  BEEF,
  TURKEY,
  FISH
}

enum CheeseType {
  GROSS_VEGAN,
  ACTUAL_COW_CHEESE,
  GOAT_CHEESE
}

enum Toppings {
  LECHUGA,
  TOMATO,
  SAUCE
}

record Taco {
  MeatType meat;
  CheeseType cheese;
  array<Toppings> toppings;
}


record Order {
  union { string, int } order_id;

  array<Taco> tacos;
}

}
```

### Schema

I generate the schema with: `avro-tools idl order.avdl protocol.avpr`

```
{
  "protocol" : "TacoRequest",
  "namespace" : "org.jeeftor.avro",
  "types" : [ {
    "type" : "enum",
    "name" : "MeatType",
    "symbols" : [ "CHICKEN", "BEEF", "TURKEY", "FISH" ]
  }, {
    "type" : "enum",
    "name" : "CheeseType",
    "symbols" : [ "GROSS_VEGAN", "ACTUAL_COW_CHEESE", "GOAT_CHEESE" ]
  }, {
    "type" : "enum",
    "name" : "Toppings",
    "symbols" : [ "LECHUGA", "TOMATO", "SAUCE" ]
  }, {
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "Taco",
    "fields" : [ {
      "name" : "meat",
      "type" : "MeatType"
    }, {
      "name" : "cheese",
      "type" : "CheeseType"
    }, {
      "name" : "toppings",
      "type" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" : "Toppings"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "Order",
    "fields" : [ {
      "name" : "order_id",
      "type" : [ "string", "int" ]
    }, {
      "name" : "tacos",
      "type" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" : "Taco"
      }
    } ]
  } ],
  "messages" : { }
}
```

My question is how to easily use this "schema" to validate input.

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON and the schema that you are trying to validate?

Comment: updated the question :)